# Get hash of ActiveRecord errors (including nested/children/relations etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this...

```rb
(byebug) model.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000560a99906bc8 @base=#<Issue id:18 gitlab-org/gitlab-shell#8>, @errors=[#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=timelogs, type=invalid, options={}>]>
(byebug) model.errors.errors.each { |error| puts error.full_message }
Timelogs is invalid
[#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=timelogs, type=invalid, options={}>]
(byebug) model.timelogs.last.errors.errors
[#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=summary, type=too_long, options={:count=>255}>]
```

I've started trying to put something together, but I feel i'm trying to reinvent the wheel:

```rb
    def all_error_messages(model)
      model.errors.each do |column, errors|
        if model.send(:"#{column}").respond_to?(:each)
          invalids = model.send(:"#{column}").reject(&:valid?)
          invalids.each do |invalid|
            invalid.errors.each do |error|
              model.errors.add(error.attribute, error.message)
            end
          end
        elsif model.send(:"#{column}").respond_to?(:errors)

        end
      end
    end
```

Is there an easy generic way to get all the errors?

Thanks

Comment: you mean this: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-group_by_attribute

Comment: @LamPhan unfortunately that still just gives me: `is invalid`

Comment: @engineersmnky I'll give it a try shortly but fairly sure it's not. I need the "too_long" error pointing to "timelogs.summary" as per my notes above.

Comment: @LeeTickett I misunderstood your question. To clarify you are looking for an out of the box way to get all error messages at N levels? If so I am completely unaware of any way to achieve this other than to write your own traversal mechanism.

Comment: damn- thanks @engineersmnky - why do you find it unlikely anyone has tackled this before? would it not be a reasonably common requirement?

Comment: @LeeTickett it is unlikely someone *hasn't* tackled this before but I am aware of a rails core implementation. As to the reasonability of this request we would need to better understand your specific reasoning as to why you desire this outcome.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky- feel free to take a look- really would be greatful https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/66793#note_636126358

Comment: posted on the github rails project too https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42883

Comment: a little progress... adding `autosave: true` or `accepts_nested_attributes_for` forces the verbose error to appear- but I still feel it shouldn't be necessary